# How to break a Roman Numeral String into its building characters?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function in JavaScript to convert roman numerals into its building character-components.

Here is an example:

- input: `"MMCDXCIV"`
- expected output: `['M', 'M', 'CD', 'XC', 'IV']`

A component consists of two characters when the first "digit" should be subtracted from the second. In other cases, the component is just the digit on itself.

I thought about using a regular expression, but I don't know how to identify such pairs with a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Just enumerate the character pairs that should be kept together:

Wikipedia explains about this [subtractive notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals):

> The numerals for 4 (IV) and 9 (IX) are written using "subtractive notation" [...] Subtractive notation is also used for 40 (XL), 90 (XC), 400 (CD) and 900 (CM). These are the only subtractive forms in standard use.

```js
let roman = 'MMCDXCIV';
let arr = roman.match(/I[VX]|X[LC]|C[DM]|./g);
console.log(arr);
```

There are other non-standard uses of subtractive notation, and if you need to cover for those, you'll need to expand the regex with those forms too.

For instance, Wikipedia mentions:

> There is, however, some historic use of subtractive notation other than that described in the above "standard": in particular IIIXX for 17, IIXX for 18, IIIC for 97, IIC for 98, and IC for 99.

Depending on the exact requirements, you could "open the door" for such deviating notations like this:

```js
for (let roman of ['IIIXX', 'IIXX', 'IIIC', 'IIC', 'IC']) {
    let arr = roman.match(/I+[VXC]|X+[LCD]|C+[DM]|./g);
    console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer with the subtractive forms that are listed on Wikipedia, where this is called "standard use". Added a phrase about non-standard subtractive notations...